# babel-watch server.js fails when running npm run dev

Tags: node.js, npm

Im currently working thru a tutorial, and have noticing that when running npm run dev, the babel-watch server.js continues to fails. I have uninstalled/reinstalled babel-cli babel-preset-env and babel-watch without success. The output of the error is

```
  npm run dev

    > back-end@1.0.0 dev /home/pietto/back-end
    > babel-watch server.js

    Watcher failure { Error: watch server.js ENOSPC
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/pietto/back-end/node_modules/chokidar          /lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/pietto/back-end/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/pietto/back-end/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/pietto/back-end/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/pietto/back-end/node_modules/chokidar  /lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
    errno: 'ENOSPC',
    code: 'ENOSPC',
    syscall: 'watch server.js',
    filename: 'server.js' }

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! back-end@1.0.0 dev: `babel-watch server.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the back-end@1.0.0 dev script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/pietto/.npm/_logs/2018-10-12T19_20_06_169Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

After some review, it was determined that I had multiple babel.rc process running in the background. Once I killed those process, worked well